# Array of conditions in SumIf with criteria in different columns

Tags: excel, sumifs

I got a simple data table and wanted to sum up the values only if two criterias are both matched, which are located in 2 different columns of each table row.

[image]

**Summing up the values for only 1 condition (month OR application) works well:**

```
=SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;H2;$E$2:$E$16)
```

**Result: token usage for different months**

Now i wanted to break down the monthly usage into the different products. E.g. the token usage for the product "AutoCAD" in the month "Jänner". These approaches i´ve tried:

```
=SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;AND(H2;D2);$E$2:$E$16)
=SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;AND("Jänner";"AutoCAD");$E$2:$E$16)
```

**Result: 0** (every value == 0)

```
=SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;{H2;D2};$E$2:$E$16)
=SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;{H2,D2};$E$2:$E$16)
```

**Result: syntax failure**

```
=SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;H2;$E$2:$E$16)+SUMMEWENN($C$2:$E$16;D2;$E$2:$E$16)
```

**Result: 26** (false, summing up separately from each other)

---

**Desired result:**

[image]

**How can i reach the desired result with inbuild excel functions?**

*(I only want to set up a VBA script if it is absolutely impossible to do otherwise).*

Comment: In your formula you refer to some ranges, but I don't see the column letters/rows in your screenshot. Is the AutoCAD column from your last screenshot the expected result or the current result with wrong result? It seems to be a pretty easy task using `SUMIFS`, but for sure I am missing something.

Comment: I added an answer, I did some assumptions, if that is not the case, please clarify it in your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMIFS` for adding multiple conditions should apply for the set you want to sum a range. For example:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$16,$C$2:$C$16,H2, $D$2:$D$16, "AutoCAD")
```

[image: sample excel file]

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was not aware that there is a second function for this, which is meant to accept multiple criteria. Works great :)